# Creating a long TCPDF document without timeout (so long running php process)

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm building a feature of a site that will generate a PDF (using TCPDF) into a booklet of 500+ pages. The layout is very simple but just due to the number of records I think it qualifies as a "long running php process". This will only need to be done a handful of times per year and if I could just have it run in the background and email the admin when done, that would be perfect. Considered Cron but it is a user-generated type of feature.

What can I do to keep my PDF rendering for as long as it takes? I am "good" with PHP but not so much with *nix. Even a tutorial link would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to change the allowed maximum execution time for PHP scripts. You can do that by several means from the script itself (you should prefer this if it would work) or by changing php.ini.

BEWARE - Changing execution time might seriously lower the performance of your server. A script is allowed to run only a certain time (30sec by default) before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. You should exactly know what you are doing before you do this.

You can find some more info about:

- setting `max-execution-time` in php.ini here http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time
- limiting the maximum execution time by `set_time_limit()` here http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

PS: This should work if you use PHP to generate the PDF. It will not work if you use some stuff outside of the script (called by `exec()`, `system()` and similar).

Answer (score 3):

Honestly you should avoid doing this entirely from a scalability perspective.  I'd use a database table to "schedule" the job with the parameters, have a script that is continuously checking this table.  Then use JavaScript to poll your application for the file to be "ready", when the file is ready then let the JavaScript pull down the file to the client.

It will be incredibly hard to maintain/troubleshoot this process while you're wondering why is my web server so slow all of a sudden.  Apache doesn't make it easy to determine what process is eating up what CPU.

Also by using a database you can do things like limit the number of concurrent threads, or even provide faster rendering time by letting multiple processes render each PDF page and then re-assemble them together with yet another process... etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

This question is already answered, but as a result of other questions / answers here, here is what I did and it worked great: (I did the same thing using pdftk, but on a smaller scale!)

I put the following code in an iframe:

```
set_time_limit(0);                   // ignore php timeout
//ignore_user_abort(true);           // optional- keep on going even if user pulls the plug*
while(ob_get_level())ob_end_clean();// remove output buffers
ob_implicit_flush(true);
```

This avoided the page load timeout. You might want to put a countdown or progress bar on the parent page. I originally had the iframe issuing progress updates back to the parent, but browser updates broke that.